# Normal width to text box in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a text box in `form-group`. As my requirement i need to restrict full width. without mention width, grid system, how can we apply normal width in bootstrap?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Phone </label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your CSS on the input field by this way -

```
 .form-group input.form-control{
      width: 400px; // or width:auto if you don't want to fix any width
      max-width: 100%; //Example
 }
```

Or You can give a new class name to apply css on a certain input field. Like this-

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label>Phone </label>
      <input class="form-control my-input" type="text">
 </div>


 .form-group .my-input{
      width: 400px;
      max-width: 100%;
 }
```

But remember, you'll have to link your CSS file after you link Bootstrap's css file in header. Plus, If you somehow can't override a CSS, you can use '!important' to override it. For example--

```
 .form-group input.form-control{
      width: 400px !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use style="width: auto" for default text box width

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Phone </label>
  <input class="form-control" style="width:auto" type="text">
</div>
```